# Python, First list index - previous list index then print

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

First of all I'm not good at English please be kind to me.
I've a trouble about my code. I need to substract previous list index from current list index.

Let me show you an example with my code;

```
xvalues = [1,1,2,3,3,3,4,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,-1,-23,-44,-512,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4]

for i in xvalues:
    print([i])
```

I need to substract previous value from current value while in for loop.
I've tried

```
for i in xvalues:
    print([i-1])
```

this but it is substract "-1" from every value in my list. I need to add this in a for loop simply;

```
[1]-[0] after this, do this ,[2]-[1] after ,do this [3]-[2]...
```

I'm looking for someone to help me and I hope this topic save someone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the below code, the subsequent subtractions are done by the new values.
For example, the first three values of the output are, `[1,0,2,...]`. Notice in the 3rd place, we get the result as `2` because of `2-0`, as 0 is the new value in the 2nd place.

```py
xvalues = [1,1,2,3,3,3,4,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,-1,-23,-44,-512,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4]

for i in range(1, len(xvalues)):
  xvalues[i] = xvalues[i] - xvalues[i-1]
```

Comment: Yes sir @illusion it is worked very well ! Thank you very much !

Comment: The example that I have given doesn't work with the code I have give. You sure this works for you right?

Comment: Yes sir ! i make some minimal changes of course but the base is your code worked very nice.

Answer (score 1):

### "I need to substract previous list index from current list index."

**Important Note:**

```
[1]-[0] after this, do this ,[2]-[1] after ,do this [3]-[2]...
```

You can try this.

```
xvalues = [1,1,2,3,3,3,4,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,-1,-23,-44,-512,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4]

for i,item in enumerate(xvalues):
    if i > 0:
        previous = xvalues[i-1]#previous = item
        print(f"{item}-({previous})")
        sub = item - previous
        print("Answer: ",sub,"\n")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1-(1)
Answer:  0 

2-(1)
Answer:  1 

3-(2)
Answer:  1 

3-(3)
Answer:  0 

3-(3)
Answer:  0 

4-(3)
Answer:  1 

1-(4)
Answer:  -3 

1-(1)
Answer:  0 

1-(1)
Answer:  0 

2-(1)
Answer:  1 

3-(2)
Answer:  1 

4-(3)
Answer:  1 

5-(4)
Answer:  1 

6-(5)
Answer:  1 

6-(6)
Answer:  0 

-1-(6)
Answer:  -7 

-23-(-1)
Answer:  -22 

-44-(-23)
Answer:  -21 

-512-(-44)
Answer:  -468 

1-(-512)
Answer:  513 

2-(1)
Answer:  1 

3-(2)
Answer:  1 

4-(3)
Answer:  1 

4-(4)
Answer:  0 

4-(4)
Answer:  0 

4-(4)
Answer:  0 

4-(4)
Answer:  0 

4-(4)
Answer:  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use zip:

```
xvalues = [1,1,2,3,3,3,4,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,-1,-23,-44,-512,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4]

for x1, x2 in zip(xvalues, xvalues[1:]):
    print(x2-x1)
```

Comment: This is the best answer for me, clearly is.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the syntax:

`[1]` creates a new list containing `1`, which is not what you want.

Let's have `x = [10, 20, 30]`, list named x containing 10, 20, 30. Then to access its values, we use `x[pos]`. Get whatever value is in list `x` at position `pos`. The position is usually called index.

```
x[0]  # returns 10
x[1]  # returns 20
x[2]  # returns 30
```

Every other positive index throws error `IndexError: list index out of range`.

We can also access the index by variable

```
i = 2
x[i]  # returns 30
```

As an answer, I recommend using zip suggested by Myccha ;).